# Firebase Flashlight DSL queries

Tags: android, elasticsearch, firebase, querydsl, flashlight

Does flashlight supports DSL queries like this:

```
  {  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "visibleName":"skye"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

?

When I put this into query field in `search/request/key/query`, it's not working, it's returning `total = 0`. But when I put a JSON query this instead: `userName:\"skye\"`, it works and returns `1 user`.

It's interesting that the above JSON works when I put it into URL query like: `~/firebase/user/_search?source={json}`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with flashlight, the current version on git is using basic querying.

Take a look at this PR and see if it fixes it for you:
https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/pull/81/commits/012aae9f577095690f31d7b528d60103761b0ff5

Comment: it didn't help :( do you have more ideas? how complicated it is to implement this feature?